# Validation of Dynamic Form Name

Tags: php, javascript

so I have the following Javascript functions I use in my PHP pages for form validation.

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/validators.php');

echo "<script Language='JavaScript' Type='text/javascript'><!--\n";
echo "function Prefix_Validator(theForm)\n";
echo "{\n";
validate_numeric('theForm', 'FieldName', 'FieldDesc');
echo "return (true);\n";
echo "}\n";
echo "//--></script>\n";
echo "\n";
```

This is what my form inputs look like:

```
echo "</td><td>\n";
echo "<input type='text' name='txtQuantity_$DeptID' size = '3' value=''>\n";
echo "</td><td>\n";
echo "<input type='text' name='txtMemo_$DeptID' size='50' value=''>\n";
echo "</font></td></tr>\n";
```

Now normally, if the name='' portion of the input was name='Qty' I could just do this with my java validation:

```
validate_numeric('theForm', 'Qty', 'Quantity');
```

But since my form uses a $variable in the name, I do not know how to use it with my Validator. This is the expanded portion of the above validator function:

```
function validate_numeric($formname, $fieldname, $fielddesc){

   echo "var checkOK = '0123456789';\n";
   echo "var checkStr = $formname.$fieldname.value;\n";
   echo "var allValid = true;\n";
   echo "var validGroups = true;\n";
   echo "var decPoints = 0;\n";
   echo "var allNum = '';\n";
   echo "for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)\n";
   echo "{\n";
   echo "ch = checkStr.charAt(i);\n";
   echo "for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)\n";
   echo "if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))\n";
   echo "break;\n";
   echo "if (j == checkOK.length)\n";
   echo "{\n";
   echo "allValid = false;\n";
   echo "break;\n";
   echo "}\n";
   echo "allNum += ch;\n";
   echo "}\n";
   echo "if (!allValid)\n";
   echo "{\n";
   echo "alert('Please enter only digit characters in the $fielddesc field.');\n";
   echo "$formname.$fieldname.focus();\n";
   echo "return (false);\n";
   echo "}\n";

   return $x;
}
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
validate_numeric('theForm', 'txtQuantity_$DeptID', 'Quantity');
```

Any suggestions would help greatly. If more information is needed, let me know and I will provide it as soon as I can.

**EDIT #1**

So I tried what you said to do with the dbl quotation marks and this is what I am seeing for the source on the page:

```
var checkOK = '0123456789';
var checkStr = theForm.txtQuantity_.value;
var allValid = true;
var validGroups = true;
var decPoints = 0;
var allNum = '';
for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
{
ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)
if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))
break;
if (j == checkOK.length)
{
allValid = false;
break;
}
allNum += ch;
}
if (!allValid)
{
alert('Please enter only digit characters in the Quantity field.');
theForm.txtQuantity_.focus();
return (false);
}
```

Shouldn't there be some sort of value after the txtQuantity_ ? on the checkStr?

I have been having so much trouble with this page, I really do think it just hates me and does whatever it can to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate_numeric('theForm', 'txtQuantity_$DeptID', 'Quantity');` Will pass literally `txtQuantity_$DeptID`. Single quotes do NOT interpret variables.

You must put that in double quotes like this at a minimum:

`validate_numeric('theForm', "txtQuantity_$DeptID", 'Quantity');`

And in certain editors it's even clearer if you do

`validate_numeric('theForm', "txtQuantity_{$DeptID}", 'Quantity');`

I also noticed your function is `echo`ing all the way down. Make sure you have one string which you `return` at the end so you do `echo validate_numeric` rather than putting it right there. Functions that output are hard to move/refactor. `$x` is completely undefined when you are returning and is probably filling your logs with notices

Comment: Alright so I tried what you said, with and without the {} and it still does not work. I edited my Question to show you what I am getting in the page source for the javascript. (Under Edit #1)

Comment: When you call the function, are you sure `$DeptID` is defined? That would be why you see an empty string as well. If you didn't see a notice for `$x` being undefined you should change your `PHP` settings to spit em out while you debug.